# move semantics unused in presence of std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, noncopyable

With the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream f;
    ifstream g;
    f = std::move(g);
}
```

Why is `ifstream::operator=(const ifstream`**&**`)` being called instead of `ifstream::operator=(ifstream`**&&**`)` even though `std::move()` is called?

**Update**: Generally speaking, is there a way to coerce a lvalue reference to a rvalue reference?

Comment: Does `istream::operator=(istream&&)` exist ?

Comment: @iammilind See sehe's answer.

Comment: @iammilind: yes it does, but it is protected (see section 27.7.2.1.2 Class basic_istream assign and swap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What evidence do you have that `ifstream::operator=(const ifstream&)` is being called?  Do you get a compile error that says you're calling this private or deleted member?

If your code is calling `ifstream::operator=(const ifstream&)`, and if your implementation is claiming to be C++11, then this is a bug in either your C++ std::lib, or compiler.  When I compile your code, `ifstream::operator=(ifstream&&)` gets called.  And this is by design.

I stuck a print statement in my implementation of `ifstream::operator=(ifstream&&)` just to be sure.  When I did your program prints out:

```
basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(basic_ifstream&& __rhs)
```

Comment: It looks like this rather annoying bug has been in gcc for a while, then. Time to open a bug report.

Comment: Also, which compiler did you use?

Comment: Sorry, this is less a gcc bug than a libstdc++ bug, due to `basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(basic_ifstream&& __rhs)` isn't even defined.

Answer (score 1):

Standard

```
 27.9.1.8 Assign and swap [ifstream.assign]

       basic_ifstream& operator=(basic_ifstream&& rhs);
```

I assume you  are looking at the wrong code (nowhere is it guaranteed that the base class operator `istream::operator=(istream&&)` **must** be called)?

---

> **Update**: Generally speaking, is there a way to coerce a lvalue reference to a rvalue reference?

Yes, it is what `std::move` does:

```
template <class T> typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t) noexcept;
```

There is also

```
template <class T> typename conditional<
  !is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value && is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
  const T&, T&&>::type move_if_noexcept(T& x) noexcept;
```

which does the same, provided that the moveconstructor is nothrow.

Comment: I forgot if it was the base class or the derived class that had `MoveAssignable`. Edited question.